# dependant dropdown list based on single table data values with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I used Codeigniter to develop dependent dropdown list by using **values of a single table**  which will allow user to click client name, based on the name user clicked.  Next dropdown list will show relevant projects with that client. Next dropdown will show task related to selected project.

But due to a bug only client name is fetched from database. No values fetched to projects and tasks. Any help? 
**Controller**

```
 <?php
    // security first always....
    (defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'));
    /**
     * Class Controller
     *
     * Class Dropdown Controller to handle login & logout
     */
    class Dropdown extends CI_controller
    {
        /**
         * Class Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            // execute parent class constructor
            parent::__construct();
            // load model
            $this->load->model('Dropdown_model');
        }

        /**
         * Default method to execute if method name missing
         * @return [type] [description]
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $array_data = array();
            // only on Ajax Request
            if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                // if request for projects
                if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'project') {
                    // get client name
                    $client     = $this->input->post('client', true);
                    // get project data by client name
                    $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($client), 'project');
                    // AjaxPOST JSON response
                    echo json_encode($array_data);die();
                }
                // if request for task
                if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'task') {
                    // get project name
                    $project    = $this->input->post('project', true);
                    // get task data by project
                    $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($project), 'task');
                    // AjaxPOST JSON response
                    echo json_encode($array_data);die();
                }
            }
            // else get all client data
            $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(null, null);
            // send to view
            $this->load->view('dropdown', ['data' => $array_data]);
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
<?php
// No direct script execution
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Class Dropdown_model to handle all related information from MySQL
 */
class Dropdown_model extends CI_Model
{
    /**
     * MySQL table which contains all data about users
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'task';
    /**
     * Returns, User First Name by Email ID
     * @param  [type] $email_addres   [description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function get_dropdown_data($where_data = null, $type = null)
    {
        $query = '';

        // clients only
        if (is_null($type) && is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('client_name');
            // only unique clients
            $this->db->distinct('client_name');
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // projects by client
        elseif ($type == 'project' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('project_name');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('client_name', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // task by project
        elseif ($type == 'task' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('task');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('project_name', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // if record exist
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            // return all data as array
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            // error
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeIgniter: Dependent dropdown list by using single table value</title>
    <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- load jquery library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- load bootstrap js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Client</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="clients" name="clients">
                <option value="0">--Select Clients--</option>
                <?php if (isset($data)):?>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$value['client_name']?>"><?=$value['client_name']?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Projects</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="projects" name="projects">
                <option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tasks</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tasks" name="tasks">
                <option value="0">--Select Tasks--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // client select box
            var $client     = $('select#clients');
            // project select box
            var $projects   = $('select#projects');
            // task select box
            var $tasks      = $('select#tasks');
            // on change client name, get projects
            $client.on('change', function () {
                // get selected client name
                var client = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                // post data with CSRF token
                var data = {
                    action:'project',
                    client: client,
                    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
                };
                // AjaxPOST to get projects
                $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
                    projects_data = '<option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>';
                    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                        projects_data += '<option value="'+obj.project_name+'">'+obj.project_name+'</option>';
                    });
                    // append all projects in project dropdown
                    $projects.html(projects_data);
                }, 'JSON');
            });
            // on change project, get task
            $projects.on('change', function () {
                // get selected project name
                var project = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
                var data = {
                    action:'task',
                    project: project,
                    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
                };
                $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
                    task_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
                    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                        task_data += '<option value="'+obj.task+'">'+obj.task+'</option>';
                    });
                    // append all task data in Task dropdown
                    $tasks.html(task_data);
                }, 'JSON');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: check the logs for error , also check the in network (developer tools of browser) when request is hit what you get in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.post('./dropdown', data, function(json)
should be $.post('.', data, function(json)

Answer (score 0):

change in your controller

```
public function index(){
  $array_data = array();
  // only on Ajax Request
  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
      // if request for projects
      if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'project') {
          // get client name
          $client     = $this->input->post('client', true);
          // get project data by client name
          $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($client), 'project');
          // AjaxPOST JSON response
          //set page header json type
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
          $this->output->set_output(json_encode($array_data));
      }
      // if request for task
      else if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'task') {
          // get project name
          $project    = $this->input->post('project', true);
          // get task data by project
          $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($project), 'task');
          // AjaxPOST JSON response
          //echo json_encode($array_data);die();
          //set page header type json
          $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
          $this->output->set_output(json_encode($array_data));
      }
  }else{
    //put all view part in else
    // else get all client data
    $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(null, null);
    // send to view
    $this->load->view('dropdown', ['data' => $array_data]);
  }

}
```

Replace all view script tag by following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // client select box
    var client     = $('select#clients');
    // project select box
    var projects   = $('select#projects');
    // task select box
    var tasks      = $('select#tasks');
    // on change client name, get projects
    client.on('change', function () {
        // get selected client name
        var client_val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // post data with CSRF token
        var data = {
            action:'project',
            client: client_val,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        // AjaxPOST to get projects
        $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
            var projects_data = '<option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                projects_data += '<option value="'+obj.project_name+'">'+obj.project_name+'</option>';
            });
            // append all projects in project dropdown
            projects.html(projects_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
    // on change project, get task
    projects.on('change', function () {
        // get selected project name
        var project = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
        var data = {
            action:'task',
            project: project,
            "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
        };
        $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
            var task_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
            $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                task_data += '<option value="'+obj.task+'">'+obj.task+'</option>';
            });
            // append all task data in Task dropdown
            tasks.html(task_data);
        }, 'JSON');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Prasad for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't show options for the second and third drodown

Comment: I Found the answer Mr.Kundan. Bug was occurred as concatenating error